# Remove sidebar margin from title page only

Tags: beamer

I have a modified theme where I want merge Torino with a side bar.
However, the sidebar space appears on my title page (left margin).
More, I can't replace the side bar title, author and blue area with the logo...
I uploaded the code in https://github.com/dnascimento/beamerLisbonTheme (everyone is welcome to help to reach the goal or use the theme)

[image: Cover]

[image: Slides]

I'm using:
`\useoutertheme{sidebar}` in my outertheme.

I guess the issue is the

```
\hbox{\hskip-\Gm@lmargin\hbox{\vbox{%
```

Gm@lmargin is modified to include the sidebar left margin. How can I include the sidebar without modify the title page?

The title page code is:

```
\defbeamertemplate*{title page alternative}{cascais theme}[1][]
{
  {\parskip0pt\offinterlineskip%
  \hbox{\hskip-\Gm@lmargin\hbox{\vbox{%
  \@tempdima=\textwidth\textwidth=\paperwidth\hsize=\textwidth\def\\{,}\vbox{}\vskip-1.5ex%
    % Title.
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=.4\paperheight,center,#1]{title page header}
      \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
      \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
        \vskip0.25em%
        {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
      \fi%     
      \vspace{.125\paperheight}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \vbox{}\vskip-\beamer@cascais@lineup%
    \vbox{}\vskip-\beamer@cascais@linemid%
    % First line.
    \hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.2\paperwidth,ht=\beamer@cascais@lineup,dp=0pt]{}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.8\paperwidth,ht=\beamer@cascais@lineup,dp=0pt]{lineup}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    }%
    \vbox{}\vskip0ex%
    % Second line.
    \hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.1\paperwidth,ht=\beamer@cascais@linemid,dp=0pt]{}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.9\paperwidth,ht=\beamer@cascais@linemid,dp=0pt]{linemid}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    }%
    % Third line.
    \hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=\beamer@cascais@linebottom,dp=0pt]{}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=\beamer@cascais@linebottom,dp=0pt]{linebottom}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    }%
    \vskip0pt%
  }}%
  \hskip-\Gm@rmargin%
  }}\hfil%
```

Comment: I uploaded the source code to:
https://github.com/dnascimento/beamerLisbonTheme

Comment: The \Gm@lmargin is modified from 21.85083pt to 59.22636pt... how can I avoid it?

Comment: Solved :)
The issue was the  \begin{columns} few lines under this paragraph.
I set: \begin{columns} {\hskip-\Gm@lmargin}

Now just replace the blue area with the logo

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved in comments